# Jmeter | Groovy functions aren't working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, json, blazemeter, groovy

I am currently following the 'Blazemeter Jmeter Pro' certification training and while working on an exercise, I noticed that for some reason, the groovy functions aren't working for me.
Let me show you:

I wrote a couple of functions in a dummy sampler like this:
[image: Notice the different functions in the request and response sections]

Then when I ran, I got the username, password and time as expected
[image: Look at the request section]

but the token response is just empty.
[image]

I got no clue and am just dumbstruck with this issue. This happened to me with the other lecture videos as well. I am guessing that this is a configuration issue. Any help is appreciated.

P.S. This is the function mentioned in the picture:

```
{"token": ${__groovy(new StringBuilder().append(${counter_variable}).append(${password_variable}).append(${time_variable}),)}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! So I have figured it out the reason by just writing it over here Damn!

Just posting it here so that someone might find it useful -

Apparently I had added a couple of randomized alphabets along with numbers in the password variable which gets appended to the token variable.

Whenever an alphabet comes into the string, it doesn't work and returns a blank line.

I changed it to just numbers like this -
[image]
and voila!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, if you want to access the variable value use `vars` shorthand instead, it stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and provides read/write access to all the JMeter Variables in the current thread scope.

You need to change this:

```
{"token": ${__groovy(new StringBuilder().append(${counter_variable}).append(${password_variable}).append(${time_variable}),)}}
```

to this:

```
{ "token" : ${__groovy(new StringBuilder().append(vars.get('counter_variable')).append(vars.get('password_variable')).append(vars.get('time_variable')).toString(),)} }
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for this tip.